# C question solved but cannot pass the test system(timeout)

Tags: c, loops

I'm a beginner in C and I've been working on my homework but I'm having trouble solving the problem

Here's the problem:

> Given the lower bound N (in pyeong) of the size of a house, and the
> set of sizes {hi} (in m2), search for the largest h satisfying the
> condition that the size is less than N. You should convert the unit to
> pyeong. Assume that one pyeong is 3.3058m2. For example, if you want a
> house no more than 5 pyeong (N = 5) and a number of sizes is
> {5.7,10.1,20.4,15.2,17.6}, the set of sizes less than or equal to 5
> pyeong is {5.7,10.1,15.2}. And the greatest one is 15.2m2, which is
> about 4.60 pyeong. Therefore, your program should print 4.60. The
> input consists of two lines in standard input. The first line contains
> the upper limit N and the second line contains the sizes of houses hi,
> separated by space. The number of sizes of the houses is greater than
> zero.
>
> Your program should find the right size h satisfying the condition,
> and calculate the translated N′ in pyeong. The output consists of two
> lines: the first line contains N′ and the second, h. All the printed
> values should be rounded up to three decimal places after the decimal
> point. If no house satisfies the condition, your program should print
> zero in both lines.

So input should be like this: (for example)

```
5 

5\.7 10.1 20.4 15.2 17.6
```

and output should be like:

```
4\.60 

15\.20
```

another example:

```
20 

59\.528 34.141 73.272 62.509 

18\.91
62\.51
```

Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int lower_bound;
    int count = 0; //the index where the element is to be inserted
    float arr[10];//initialize an array
    float pyeong = 3.3058;
    

    //get lower bound
    scanf("%d", &lower_bound);
    //get the size(float numbers)
    do {
        scanf("%f", &arr[count++]);

    }while (getchar() != '\n');

    //resize the array
    //arr[count];

    //print array element
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        if(arr[i] < lower_bound*pyeong){
            if(arr[i]> arr[0]){ //compare which one is bigger
                arr[0] = arr[i];//put the bigger one in the front
            }
        }else{
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    //printf("%.2f\n", lower_bound*pyeong);
    printf("%.2f\n", arr[0]/pyeong);
    printf("%.2f\n", arr[0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've tested my code in both VS code and Codeblock and when I uploaded on the code testing platform(designed by school), it showed a "timeout" message.

May I know if the loops in the program is causing an error? Please provide valuable feedback and improvements to be made in the code.

Comment: "_All the printed values should be rounded up to three decimal places after the decimal point._" `"%.2f\n"` ain't gonna meet requirements... May or may not be the problem...

Comment: `while (getchar() != '\n');` Not all text files end with `\n`... Some editors can save a file with a "dangling" last word (or whatever..) Maybe look into that...

Comment: Yeah but the test codes were provided by professor and I tested them both in VScode and code block, I got the right output. So I think decimal point is not the cause of the problem because test system showed "timeout". Does those loops I write take too much time? But I can't come up with other solution...

Comment: `echo "foo\nbar" | studentsProg`... One possible "test harness" that omits the expected trailing newline... Your program will sit and wait until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of assignments it did. Use that value!!! `while (scanf("%f", &arr[count]) == 1) { count++; } /* no getchar!! */` Assume input is well formatted (it usually is in these kind of exercises, unlike when dealing with real human beings)

Comment: You are limiting your array to `10` elements. Maybe there's an input with more than that? Unless there is a restriction you omitted...

Comment: Are you sure the example data are correct? In the third example (with `N` equal `20`) you should get 62.509*3.3058 = 18.909 (or 18.91, depending on rounding position), but not 18.19.

Comment: Yes the answer is 18.91 (I typed it wrong and now I fixed it!) Thank you for reminding.

Comment: @pmg I tried the syntax you recommended, but after I entered a series numbers of size, it didn't print out the output but still accepting input.

Comment: Ah! That's kind of expected, my bad. You can stop the program from accepting input with `EOF` (`Ctrl+D` on Un*x, `Ctrl+Z` on Windows) or with an invalid input like a letter. In most (all?) online programming sites, the `EOF` is already there automatically without you having to do anything.

Comment: @pmg Thank you for your explanation! But it still showed "timeout" error message. I will ask professor for help to check whether my code is wrong or there is another problem resulting in timeout on next week of the class. Will post the outcome after getting the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is common in competitive programming. If you search for "TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED" on google it provides possible reasons and solutions to it.

The point I noted in your code is `lower_bound` is fixed and `const float pyeong = 3.3058;` should be const. So why perform multiplication every time?

it should be like:

```
float area = lower_bound*pyeong;

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    if(arr[i] < area){
        if(arr[i]> arr[0]){ //compare which one is bigger
            arr[0] = arr[i];//put the bigger one in the front
        }
    }else{
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! I just fixed the code and tried one more time, but it still showed a "timeout" message.

Comment: All the printed values should be rounded up to three decimal places after the decimal point." Use `%.3f`

Comment: But I think it's running time problem. If the cause of error is decimal point, I should've got zero point. Still trying because I got only 4 chances left to test my code :(

Comment: use `float output = 0;` instead of using `arr[0]` and skip the `else` part. just use `if((arr[i] < area) && (output < arr[i])) output = arr[i];` in for loop.

Comment: I just uploaded the code file again and the whole page just went blank! I took a loop at the console it showed a "cannot load due to access control check". I was wondering whether the test system went wrong or not.